# Simulating 2 columns for 4 successive divs

Tags: css, html, layout

I have 4 successive `div`s:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="child">A</div>
    <div class="child">B</div>
    <div class="child">C</div>
    <div class="child">D</div>
</div>
```

Assuming each child `div` has varying content, of different heights, and a margin added for clarity, it displays as follows:

[image: Display 1]

**Without** changing the HTML in any way (no adding classes to the `div`s, no adding intermediary column `div`s), I would like to achieve this layout:

[image: Display 2]

The order in which the `div`s are placed does not matter much.

I've tried things along the lines of:

```
.child { width: 50%; }
.child:nth-child(even) { float: left; }
.child:nth-child(odd) { float: right; }
```

But the alignnments are off. Does any CSS wizard have an idea?

Comment: If the heights are completely random, I don't believe there is a way to do it. I say that having tried many times (I've posted a lot of answers on this subject). For your case, I would probably use a few lines of JavaScript to add wrapping column `div`s. For the general case, use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/5VYk8/)

```
.container {
    width:220px; /* (child width)x2 + (child margin)x4 */
}
.child {
    margin:5px;
    background-color:#FF0080;
    width:100px;
}
.child:nth-child(even) {
    float: left;
}
.child:nth-child(odd) {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: If you want the divs to go from left to right in order, just change the direction of the floats around.

Comment: @Younes: That no longer matches the original requirement of having no vertical gaps between elements (other than the margin).

Comment: @thirtydot Ah, missed that part.

Comment: For the sake of my current project, I can work with the gap, but for the sake of this S/O question, I'll keep the original requirement (might come in handy for someone else in the future).

Answer (score 1):

Well you could use CSS columns, which has [good partial support across browsers (primarily prefixed though), but full support is not so great](http://caniuse.com/#search=column).

Give them a try:

```
.container { 
    -webkit-column-width: 250px; 
    -moz-column-width: 250px; 
    column-width: 250px; 
    width: 520px; 
    background: yellow;
}
.child { 
    background: red; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Take a look at this jsfiddle for a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/xwwe3/ (complete with My First Colours to demonstrate what is happening).

The columns are set to 250px wide, which I found the `.child` didn't obey until given `display: inline-block; width: 100%;`. Then the width of `.container` is set to 520px to give the columns a gutter width of 10px with two columns (250 * 2 + 10 = 520)

So depending on whether you think the support is acceptable for your use case is up to you. Tweaking the heights of the `.child` elements does make some weird stuff happen, but I'd suggest you read up further on CSS columns and try and work out what is going there.

Alternatively, [jQuery masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) is a popular way of achieving this.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to fix (for example) this scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/xwwe3/1/. I could be wrong though, I haven't used CSS3 columns very much.

Comment: Yeah, short of giving the container a fixed height: http://jsfiddle.net/xwwe3/2/ I think you might be right, but I laso haven't used them very much either.